# Are there any secret taunts in Super Smash Bros 4?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Are there any secret taunts in Super Smash Bros 4? I remember back in Brawl there was I think Snake and he had some Codec calls, and Star Fox and Falco and Wolf all had secret conversations on Corneria and Lylat Cruise.

Are there any secret taunts in Super Smash Bros 4 for the 3DS?  I've tried doing the down-taunt thing with Fox on the Corneria stage, but nothing happens.  So I assume there's no secret taunt there.

Comment: [There is indeed still a secret taunt on Corneria.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c63IC6IF7i0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still secret taunts like the Fox one. There is one when you are Pit and the stage is Palutena's Temple that Palutena gives you advice on the fighter you are currently fighting. It is called "Palutena's Advice".

Answer (score 8):

The [star fox secret taunt](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Fox_Smash_Taunt) is still in the game, and it works as usual. Here's a picture as proof.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is one. If you use fox down taunt,it will do the same like brawl did with the whole "calling peppy and slippy" thing again

Comment: Do you have any source?